# How to hide number button on UIKeyboard?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uikeyboard

Is there a way to hide **number button** and **space button**?

[image]

*Mantaining UIKeyboard **transparency***??

I need a keyboard with only letters, backspace and NEXT button, nothing else.
I need compatibility from iOS 3.1+!

thanks.

Comment: -1 ??? It's so stupid as question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page has a great tutorial about customizing a keyboard](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key).  Looks like you might be able to use this to hide the buttons you don't want, or change the current buttons.

Basically, you should register as an observer for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

and do customization inside your `keyboardWillShow:` notification handler:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification { 
    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard view found; add the customization to it
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
            UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            // do stuff to customView here
            [keyboard addSubview:customView];
    }
}
```

The prefix `@"<UIKeyboard"` in this line `if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)` might be different.  So you should loop through once using `NSLog` to print out all the subview descriptions to see what string you need to check for.

---

And here is some info about the default keyboards that are provided (non-customized)

[UIKeyboardType - The type of keyboard to display for a given text-based view.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardTypeDefault)

Check out [this UIKeyboardType page](http://gprince.yolasite.com/index/uikeyboardtype) for images of each keyboard type.

Here are some definitions from [UITextInputTraits Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardTypeDefault)

```
typedef enum {
   UIKeyboardTypeDefault,
   UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,
   UIKeyboardTypeURL,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,
   UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,
   UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,
   UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable
} UIKeyboardType;
```

> - UIKeyboardTypeDefault
>
> Use the default keyboard for the current input method. Available in
>   iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> - UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable
>
> Use a keyboard that displays standard ASCII characters. Available in
>   iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> - UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation
>
> Use the numbers and punctuation keyboard. Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later.
>
> - UIKeyboardTypeURL
>
> Use a keyboard optimized for URL entry. This type features “.”, “/”,
>   and “.com” prominently. Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> - UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad
>
> Use a numeric keypad designed for PIN entry. This type features the
>   numbers 0 through 9 prominently. This keyboard type does not support
>   auto-capitalization. Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> - UIKeyboardTypePhonePad
>
> Use a keypad designed for entering telephone numbers. This type
>   features the numbers 0 through 9 and the “*” and “#” characters
>   prominently. This keyboard type does not support auto-capitalization.
>   Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> - UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad
>
> Use a keypad designed for entering a person’s name or phone number.
>   This keyboard type does not support auto-capitalization. Available in
>   iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> - UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress
>
> Use a keyboard optimized for specifying email addresses. This type
>   features the “@”, “.” and space characters prominently. Available in
>   iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> - UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad
>
> Use a keyboard with numbers and a decimal point. Available in iOS 4.1
>   and later.
>
> - UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet
>
> Deprecated. Use UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable instead. Available in iOS
>   2.0 and later.

Comment: Perfect, i know ...and then? Your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from making your own keyboard (it's not that difficult) use UITextField and the delegate method to filter the input.

Comment: Beware of making your own keyboard- Apple doesn't like it that much and may reject your app.